# Stop multiple playing videos on page using embedded JWPlayer

Tags: video, jwplayer

Am using JWPlayer to display the videos in my site. I have looped the videos from module using the placeholder [[module_video]].

```
<iframe src="[[module_video]]" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But my issue is if I click the first video and again click the second video its not stop the first video. Which means In my page I want to show the only one video which should play. If user click any other video then the previous one must be stopped.

How I can do this using embedded JWplayer?

**EDIT 1:**

The values for `[[module_video]]` will be like the following url `//content.jwplatform.com/players/sample-test.html` this kind of URL. So when I frame gets load the video gets played. Multiple URL will be entered for the different entry, so whenever the page loads all video are in the page, if I click it should play the particular video alone.

**EDIT 2**

Actually I have a different video for each entry. In my overview page am displaying those entry with the video. While add the entries I will add the video link of the entry like 
`http://leanbackplayer.com/example_iframe.html` in my module.

In my overview page I will display the videos from the module by the placeholder `[[module_video]]`. So in my overview page will display the Entry name and video of all the entries. In this case I want to stop the video which all are playing except the last one.

Comment: Do have the jwp code that `[[module_video]]`  is located? Ids of each player?

Comment: yes, I will add the code in my module, so that when the loop begins the `[[module_video]]` will fetch the record.

Comment: Ok, then I'll give you something that'll work for a **normal setup** and then you can figure out the ids.

Comment: Oh!!.. Okay.. Please @zer00ne

Comment: hi @Jack,  if you want to play multiple videos. Why are you loading single video from html page. Can you not keep all videos in single page and keep a video playlist and implement `mutually exclusive playback` - https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439797-example-mutually-exclusive-playback

>>Also, have you thought of **generating iframe dynamically** ??
**Share your thought and more of your code of [[module_name]], so that we can help you with correct answer**

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

The ids are jwp1, jwp2, and jwp3

```
  jwp1.on('play',function(){ pauseOthers(1); });
  jwp2.on('play',function(){ pauseOthers(2); });
  jwp3.on('play',function(){ pauseOthers(3); });

  function pauseOthers(target) { 
    for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
       if(i != target) { jwplayer("jwp"+i).pause(true); }
    }
  };
```

Usage

`pauseOthers(3);`

// jwp3 will play and jwp1 and jwp2 will pause

Ref: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439797-example-mutually-exclusive-playback

Comment: You are mistaken, In my `[[module_video]]` will give the result like `//content.jwplatform.com/players/sample-test.html`  this kind of url. So when i frame gets load the video gets played.

Multiple URL will be entered for the different entry, so whenever the page loads all video are in the page, if i click it should play the particular video alone

Comment: Unfortunately because you are using IFRAME's which are loading a page from a different domain to the parent page (*.jwplatform.com), you will not be able to access the players programmatically. Do you have any control over the page/code being loaded in the IFRAME?

Comment: @Jack It's just as Mr. @jherrieven says. If you have control of the `src` (ex. `page1.html, page2.html, page3.html`) **and** each in the same domain as your main page (i.e. the page with 3 iframes) it may be feasible. If you embed the JW Player in each page, there is a way to control them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using embedded player on my site and have a script to listen to 'play' events and on that event have a loop iterate over active video elements pausing them all but the active one:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    console.log(videos);
    for(var i = 0, len = videos.length; i < len;i++){
        if(videos[i] != e.target){
            videos[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```